# How to solve and rectify this error message

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to register with online jobs and as i save the registration which is page 4 of my information details, i get this message: (which i really don't understand)

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'craigslist_posting_marketing' in 'field list'

> INSERT INTO `jobseekers_skills` (`ability_to_solve_problems_quickly`,
>   `attention_to_detail`, `email`, `gathering_information`,
>   `google_docs`, `internet_browsing`, `learning_new_skills_rapidly`,
>   `ms_power_point`, `ms_excel`, `ms_office`, `typing_speed`,
>   `working_at_a_fast_pace`, `general_experience`, `general_explanation`,
>   `speaking`, `writing`, `english_experience`, `english_explanation`,
>   `advertising`, `blogging`, `branding`, `copywriting`,
>   `email_marketing`, `google_adsense`, `google_adwords`,
>   `google_webmaster`, `recording_audio`, `seo`, `telemarketing`,
>   `video_marketing`, `video`, `video_editing`, `marketing_experience`,
>   `marketing_explanation`, `autoresponders`,
>   `backing_up_mysql_database`, `drupal`, `ftp`, `google_analytics`,
>   `html`, `joomla`, `managing_servers`, `microsoft_excel`, `web_pages`,
>   `wordpress`, `webmaster_experience`, `webmaster_explanation`,
>   `adobe_after_effects`, `corel_draw`, `css`, `dreamweaver`,
>   `fireworks`, `flash`, `logo_design`, `maya`, `pagemaker`, `photoshop`,
>   `videography`, `web_page_design`, `graphics_experience`,
>   `graphics_explanation`, `ajax`, `asp_net`, `autocad`, `csharp`,
>   `cplusplus`, `coldfusion`, `database`, `delphi`, `flex`, `java`,
>   `javascript`, `jquery`, `opengl`, `oracle`, `perl`, `php`, `python`,
>   `ruby`, `visual_basic`, `programming_experience`,
>   `programming_explanation`, `accounting`, `bookkeeping`,
>   `budgeting_forecasting`, `business_analysis`, `business_plans`,
>   `corporate_strategy`, `financial_analysis`, `financial_forecasting`,
>   `financial_management`, `inventory_management`, `investment_research`,
>   `payroll`, `peachtree`, `project_management`, `strategic_planning`,
>   `tax_preparation`, `finance_management_experience`,
>   `finance_management_explanation`, `customer_support`, `data_entry`,
>   `event_planner`, `medical_transcription`, `research`,
>   `telephone_handling`, `time_management`, `travel_planning`,
>   `admin_support_experience`, `admin_support_explanation`,
>   `craigslist_posting_marketing`, `direct_mail_marketing`,
>   `posting_listings_online`, `prospecting`, `reo_asset_management`,
>   `telephone_support`, `trustee_sale_tracking`,
>   `real_estate_experience`, `real_estate_explanation`, `jobseeker_id`)
>   VALUES ('4', '4', '4', '3', '1', '4', '3', '3', '3', '1', '3', '3',
>   'I\'m steady and calculating. I like to be sure of what I\'m doing,
>   and not just doing it fast for the sake of getting it done and over
>   with. ', '', '4', '4', 'I actually consider it my first language.\nI
>   have taught Great Britain and US 101 classes.', '', '3', '3', '2',
>   '4', '3', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1', '4', '1', '3', '3', 'Yes, marketing
>   communication skills training.', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
>   '1', '1', '3', '3', '1', 'Just with Excel and the web.', '', '2', '1',
>   '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '3', '3', '1', 'Dabbled with
>   Photoshop,Videography. ', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
>   '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'None', 'None',
>   '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1', '1',
>   '1', '1', 'Need more practice.', '', '4', '2', '3', '1', '1', '4',
>   '4', '4', 'I\'ve done ok with it.', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
>   '1', 'None', 'None', '92369')

HELP!! Many thanks!

Comment: Sure the columns actually spelt craigslist_posting_marketing, and not got a typo and perhaps its "craiglist_posting_marketing"

Comment: What's not to understand on a message that says column `craigslist_posting_marketing` does not exist in table `jobseekers_skills`?

Comment: If I knew the bleeding answer, do you think I'd bother typing all that bshcrglstig, huh, Miss-know-it-all Feeela? DUH. I'm obviously not as 'techie' as you are.. kz I happen to have a life outside your box.
You shouldn't be allowed in here, you know.. kz seemingly to me, you're not really interested in helping.. just being cocky and very boorish.

Answer (score 2):

The message is clear, the `craigslist_posting_marketing` doesn't exist in the `jobseekers_skills` table, so check the field names of the table fix the SQL sentence and try again.

Comment: Thank you, Ballon head tomtom.. your answer is truly helpful.